# How to handle OAuth 2.0 with a REST API for public and private application?

Tags: api, rest, oauth-2.0, authorization, laravel-5.1

Currently, I'm working on a REST API which will be available for public clients but also I wanted to use it in my mobile application.

For the public clients, I considered to use the Clients Credentials grant, in this case, they would have to registered their app in my Web application which will give them the client key and client secret, then, they could request the access token with them and also I could know the user related to the credentials

But with my mobile application, I'll need to have a sign in section where I would need to use Authorization Code grant in order to secure my data, but I'm not sure if it's necessary.

Based on this, I have a couple of questions:
1. The Authorization Code grant it's the best way to do it? 
2. It's a bad practice to have two authorization flows in the same endpoint? 
3. Dropbox, Twitter, etc...all of them have REST API, how do they manage authorization in their own apps?

Thanks beforehand and sorry for all questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve this with two alternatives and for the moment, I'm going with the first one.

1. Create an Authorization server with a parameter that indicates what kind of Authorization Grant it's asking to use and in this way I can decide which kind of flow will follow based on this. I follow the OAuth 2.0 Spec for this using the correct names and parameters to pass in order to have a good way to authenticate our clients and applications.
2. Create an API gateway where I can send all the authentication requests for my API's using Node.js and in there it will be decided which API it's asking for authentication and with kind of Authorization Grant it's using. You can have more information about this in here:

https://www.nginx.com/blog/building-microservices-using-an-api-gateway/